# Page navigation not working correctly on index but only on categories

Tags: pagination, navigation, noindex

i have a problem with the page navigation, on the homepage of my website page navigation not working, when i click on page number 2 or 3 it says "Not found".

But in the categories page is working fine, only on the homepage gives this problem.

Actually im using the default permalinks.

Here is the website if you want to try and test it www.onstreaming.net

Here is the index:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

<?php 
$postct = get_option('dion_postnum'); 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array('post_type' => 'videos','post_status'=> 'publish','posts_per_page' =>$postct,'caller_get_posts'  =>1,'paged' =>$paged,);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>

<div class="box rounded <?php if (++$counter % 4 == 0) { echo "lastbox"; }?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<?php require('postcover.php'); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="navigation">
<?php
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
?>

</div>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="title"><h2>Oops.. Nothing Found !</h2></div>
    <div class="cover"> <p>I think what you are looking for is not here or it has been moved. Please try a different search..</p> </div>


<?php endif; ?>

</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So i hope somebody can help me with this big problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Andre, you are using $paged variable as an argument for your query, but you haven't declared that variable. Try declaring that variable above the arguments using:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Moreover its better to use the content for postcover.php on the same page instead.

Comment: And where should i paste this code exactly ?

Comment: You can paste this code above query posts arguments. I have edited your code and added the required variable.

Comment: i have tried a couple of times but it gives me the same problem =( any other idea ?

Comment: Anybody can help me ?